# how to pass subnet to tfvars? using terraform for azure subnets

Tags: azure, terraform

i have a subnet module like this:

```
    module "subnet" {
  source = "../../azurerm/azurerm-subnet"

  business_unit       = var.business_unit
  location            = var.location
  region              = var.region
  resource_group_name  = var.vnet_resource_group
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
  address_prefixes     = var.address_prefixes
}
```

how can pass these values to a tfvars file?

Comment: It's actually the other way around. You are not passing the values to a tfvars file, rather tfvars file is providing the necessary values for variables that are defined.

Answer (score 1):

During your terraform plan execution you should pass your values in a tfvars file.
command: `terraform plan "-var-file=subnet.tfvars"`
In your subnet.tfvars pass values like this:

```
business_unit       = "IT"
location            = "Your VNET Location"
region              = "..."
resource_group_name  = "Your VNET RG Name"
virtual_network_name = "Your VNET Name"
address_prefixes     = "A suitable address prefix like 10.0.1.0/24"
```